# Apache: Only enable certain sslciphersuites

Tags: apache, encryption, sslengine

I have two questions.

**First one:** I checked which cipher suites are supported by firefox ( *https:// cc. dcsec.uni-hannover. de/* ).

Example:
Cipher Suite Name: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Key Size: 256 Bit
Description: Key exchange: ECDH, encryption: AES, MAC: SHA1.
is supported.

How can I enable only this chiper suite in the apache configuration?

This configuration doesn't work:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
```

*Whats wrong?*

**Second one:** On *https:// calomel.org / firefox_ssl_validation.html* on chapter "256 bit Perfect Forward Secrecy only" the following chipers are recommanded

```
dhe_dss_aes_256_sha
dhe_dss_camellia_256_sha
dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha
dhe_rsa_camellia_256_sha
ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_sha
ssl3.ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_sha
```

The chapter "SSLCipherSuite Directive" on *https:// httpd.apache.org/ docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html* doesn't help to configure the apache in the right way. How can I "translate" e. g. dhe_dss_aes_256_sha in a proper configuration for the SSLCipherSuite.

**Thanks in advance for reading and your help.**